# Oracle Batch Processing

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

I need to update 2 million records in DB, and for that I need to update it in batches. For e.g. first update 500k batch and then do commit and then do another 500k batch update.

Can anyone help me here with the batch update examples ?

Update query:

```
UPDATE "user" 
  SET cosid = 10
where msisdn_1 not in (SELECT C_MSISDN 
                       FROM SBM_SUBSCRIPTION a, 
                            SBM_SUBSCRIBER b 
                       WHERE a.N_SUBSCRIBER_ID=b.N_ID)
```

Comment: Why do you think you need to "update in batches"? Running an update in a single transaction is usually much faster

Comment: Why do you need to do it in batches? It is less efficient and makes it harder to recover from failures. What proportion of the rows in the table will you be updating - 2 million out of how many? (Recreating the table *might* be faster, but has its own issues of course).

Comment: As others have told, single transaction is much efficient. But, if you worry about issues like *unable to extend temp segment*, you should consider bulk update with forall : https://blogs.oracle.com/oraclemagazine/bulk-processing-with-bulk-collect-and-forall

Comment: I will be updating 2 million records out of 19 million.
The main reason is to avoid issues, and we can recover the update if done in batches, NO ?

Answer (score 0):

I like this way of updating when I have to commit intermittently to avoid rollback/redo issues

the sql%rowcount will contain how many rows are updated, when it gets to 0 you know all your rows have been updated

The rownum < 1000 is just an example, you could make that bigger based on your rollback/redo size

it will do a pass through the table for each loop so try to make it a larger number if you can

```
begin
   loop
      update x set yyy=zzz where bb=cc and rownum < 1000;
      exit when sql%rowcount = 0;
      commit;
   end loop;
   commit;
end;
/
```

Comment: Hello Peter M,

Thanks for this but there is / at the end ? is it typo or its the part of your example?

Comment: yes, there is a "/" at the end -- when you run it from sql plus you need that -- if you run it from a program you don't need that